# Generating a set of permutation given a set of numbers and some conditions on the relative positions of the elements

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinatorics, backtracking

I am looking for an algorithm which, given a set of numbers {0, 1, 2, 4, 5...} and a set of conditions on the relative positions of each element, would check if a valid permutation exists. The conditions are always of type "Element in position i in the original array must be next(adjacent) to element in position j or z".
The last and first element in a permutation are considered adjacent.

Here's a simple example:

Let the numbers be {0, 1, 2, 3}
and a set of conditions: a0 must be next to a1, a0 must be next to a2, a3 must be next to a1
A valid solution to this example would be {0,1,3,2}.

Notice that any rotation/symmetry of this solution is also a valid solution. I just need to prove that such a solution exists.

Another example using the same set:
a0 must be next to a1, a0 must be next to a3, a0 must be next to a2.

There is no valid solution for this example since a number can only adjacent to 2 numbers.

The only idea I can come up with right now would be to use some kind of backtracking.
If a solution exists, this should converge quiet fast. If no solution exists, I can't imagine any way to avoid checking all possible permutations. 
As I already stated, a rotation or symmetry doesn't affect the result for a given permutation, therefor it should be possible to reduce the number of possibilities.

Comment: Do you have restristrictions or requirements for the size of the Sets? Is there a reason not to use brute forcing? Is (x nextTo y) the only form of constraint?

Comment: x next to y is the only constraint, however it is possible to have a more loose constraint of the kind x next to (y or z) which make this harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulate this as a graph problem. Connect every pair of numbers that need to be next to each other. You are going to end up with a bunch of connected component. Each component has a number of permutations (lets call them mini-permutations), and you can have a permutation of the components.

When you create the graph make sure each component follows a bunch of rules: no cycles, no vertices with more than two vertices etc.

Comment: I'll implement this and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to know if you can create chains of numbers. Put each number into a chain which keeps track of the number and up to two neighbors. Use the rules to join chains together. When you join two chains you'll end up with a chain with two loose ends (neighbors). If you can get through all the rules without running out of loose ends then it works.

Comment: This is kind of the solution I'm asking for. The issue is that some rules can be loose (a0 can be next to (a1 or a2)) which adds some potential domino effect. (a0 can be next to (a1 or a2), a2 must be next to (a3 or a4). The second rule force the choice of a1 in the first rule. Do you think this can be coupled with the graph solution proposed by @ElKamina?

Comment: If you have OR's in the rules, then you'll likely have to try solutions and perform backtracking if they fail.  Start with the hard rules - the ones without the OR's then methodically try each combination of the ORs until you hit one that succeeds.  I suspect that this would be roughly equivalent to the graph algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the graph solution with a slight modification.

If a node has too many neighbors, the algorithm would drop one edge and check the graph again.
I then use backtracking to roll back and check if it is possible to drop the next edge...
This method give the same result as the brute force method I wrote.

In term of complexity, this solution seems to be better than the brute force although I can't run it on more than 20 numbers(only 8 for the brute-force). In a sens, this is logical since such graph can actually generate a subset of valid permutation at once, plus in the worst case, it is equivalent to finding some compositions over the set of edges. It is backtracking after all.

Given that rotation doesn't have any effect on the validity of permutations, I was thinking about fixing the a0 in the first position(This can be achieved by simply rotating a valid permutation till a0 is in the first position) and then try to build the solution from there.

Using DP I might get something better than exponential complexity. But I must say that i'm still not sure where to begin :)